# Using Python to get the child __class__ not the base class

Tags: python

I want to get the class of the sender in the code below using `sender.__class__`. This works until I have a model that inherits from a base class.

For example sender is class Profile but `sender.__class__` gives the base bass Profile inherits from MPTTModelBase (which is `abstract = True`). Same thing with `.Meta` etc.

```
@receiver(post_save)
def send_func(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

    print(sender) #<class 'demo.apps.t.models.Profile'>
    print(sender.__class__) # <class 'mptt.models.MPTTModelBase'>
```

How do I get the class ignoring inherited models (if it has one)?

Comment: `sender` *is* the class itself for this signal.

Comment: I see, so ``sender.__class__`` is going down another level? But why if I do ``sender.Meta`` does it get the MPTTModelBase Meta. should it not get senders?

Comment: Indeed, `sender.__class__` gets you the [metaclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python). You would use `sender._meta` to access the meta options once the class has been loaded.

Comment: I see that makes sense now. could you add this as an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most django signals, the sender of the signal is the class itself. Here, you get `sender` as the class and the actual object is `instance`.

So what you will get is:

- `sender.__class__`: the [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) of your model.
- `sender._meta`: the [model's Meta](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/meta/) options. You get it here because Django removes the `Meta` from the model and makes options available as `_meta`, which it augments with some methods.

Comment: Yes, it is very handy for all kind of generic code that needs to examine the model. If you use a version of Django older than 1.8, beware that it changed a lot from django 1.7 to django 1.8.